# Authentication with Django rest-auth works properly only with a superuser. In other cases I get - Unable to log in with provided credentials

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

Any ideas why rest-auth authentication works properly only with a superuser? When I try to log in user without staff and superuser permission I get the error shown below. During registration the user is created properly.

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide more info: what fields do you send in the authentication request?

Comment: My request body looks like this `{
 "email": "john@gmail.com",
 "password": "mypassword"
}`. It works properly only when I send email and password of the superuser. In other case I get `{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Unable to log in with provided credentials."
    ]
}` Do you know what may cause an error?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this happen's because you have to send username as well.

Try adding `username` field to your request, which will have same value as `email`

And add this configuration to your settings.py file:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

Comment: It was my fault, I forgot that I have defined own register serializer `REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
   'REGISTER_SERIALIZER':'backend.serializers.MyRegisterSerializer',
}` Now everything works properly.